# Is there a book or online source explaining Jewish year-"type" sequences?

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, jewish-books, calendar

The current Judaic calendar allows for three types of year lengths:

- Chaser ("missing") - 353 days
- Kesidra ("in order") - 354 days
- Shalem ("full") - 355 days

(Add 30 to each of the above for leap years.)

Is there a set of rules that explain the sequence / possibilities of the year types? For example, I noticed that this year, 5779 is a leap year / shaleim and 5780 will be a non-leap year shaleim . Offhand, I don't recall two maleh years concecutively, and I assume that this can occur only if one is a leap year and the other is not. (I.e., you wouldn't see two consecutive non-leap shleimim.)

I gather that the sequence depends mainly on the day of week that Rosh Hashanna begins as there are a limited number of *kviyot* allowed for each possible weekday. But, I haven't been able to locate something that explains the possible sequence of the year types.

Comment: You can figure this all out by yourself with 10 minutes, a pencil, and paper. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75798/759

Comment: It's not so common, but you can have two non-leap shleimah years consecutively, for example 5739 and 5740 were בשה and זשג.

Comment: Are you looking for the chart in the Tur OH 428 ?

Comment: @פריזהב, note that the standard printing of that chart has mistakes in it. The one in Pri Chadash, same siman, is much more accurate.

Comment: @Meir - Good point. The Biur Halacha beginning of 428 notes that, but the new Tur Machon Shiras Devorah has a corrected one based on earlier printings of the Tur.

Comment: @פריזהב I am familiar with the Tur chart. That just lists the *kviot* as they are. I'm looking for something more general that explains the rules or possibilities. I have to look at DoubleAA's link. They may suffice for my needs.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113711/video-course-on-jewish-calendar
(Maybe overdoing it for your question)

Answer (score 1):

An excellent work, written by a major Torah authority but geared for the layman, is "[The Jewish Calendar: It Structures and Laws](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578193462.html)" by [Rav David Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovid_Feinstein).

From the Product description (linked above):

> When the Syrian-Greeks - in the time of Chanukah - wanted to undermine
> and eventually destroy Jewish life, one of the three commandments they
> tried to abolish was the proclamation of Rosh Chodesh. They knew that
> without a calendar as ordained by the Torah, the festivals could not
> be observed and major components of Jewish life would come to a
> standstill.
>
> Today, there is no Sanhedrin, no means of establishing
> Rosh Chodesh according to sightings of the new moon. How is our
> present-day calendar designed? What are its complex computations? Why
> can't Rosh Hashanah fall out on Sunday, Wednesday, or Friday? How are
> the leap years determined, and how is it that the solar years and
> lunar years are kept in equilibrium?
>
> These are only a few of the many problems that are analyzed and clarified in this brilliant presentation by HaGaon Harav David Feinstein, Rosh Yeshivah of
> Mesivtha Tifereth Jerusalem, and one of the world's great poskim.
>
> There is much more in this stellar book. It presents the Rosh
> Yeshivah's insights into all the special days of the Jewish calendar,
> explanations of their laws, and reasons for many of our familiar but
> sometimes mysterious customs.

Comment: Thanks. I bought this book a few months ago. It is well organized and excellent reading. I haven't yet found an answer to my question within this book, but, I have to search a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hakirah journal article [here](http://www.hakirah.org/vol20Ajdler.pdf) that describes how the calendar works. The leap years, year sequences, and which days yom tov can't fall out and such things.

Comment: A short summary of what it says would improve this answer. Thanks for posting!