# Video course on Jewish Calendar

Tags: calendar, adult-learning

I made an (elementary) video on the Jewish Calendar, which goes through the basic principles from beginning to end, and actually uses them to calculate the full calendar for 5780. It came in just under an hour.
I don't mean to advertise (instead of asking a question), but I wonder
a) Does another such course exist?
b) What would be good venues to find people interested in watching such a course?
I could post the link(s) to Google Drive and youtube, but I don't mean to violate the site rules, if there are any. If someone does watch it,
c) How could it be improved?

Here are the links to [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com/open?id=1YvMmc0kB0uQ2Ws7dQWV4SkJ22G0OmFN6) and [youtube](http://youtube.com/channel/UC8L25iBp_ZUias3gnvtFJTA?view_as=subscriber).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you send a link? I'd like to watch it. Thanks.

Comment: Good that you added to your question about asking about site rules.

Comment: Here's the link to Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YvMmc0kB0uQ2Ws7dQWV4SkJ22G0OmFN6 and youtube https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8L25iBp_ZUias3gnvtFJTA?view_as=subscriber

Comment: Thanks. I will watch them.

Comment: Be interested to hear what you think. (I have found that I can watch it at 1.25 speed without losing comprehension; apparently I talk slowly.)

Comment: Very nice video, but by chance, do you have just the slides. I don't mean to be offensive, but I don't have an extra hour of time unfortunately but i want to learn what you wrote about.

Comment: Never thought of that. Try this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Ewte1T8Q8zzWn8Ers9xZZ2ZTKRJ7D6c, for PowerPoint. The slides still contain audio, and in some cases video. I could think about making a version without any of that, if you'll tell me that they can be understood stand-alone.

Comment: I'd add that without the video sections, you might need some additional software pieces, where I move around on a "calendar web page" https://drive.google.com/open?id=12uFNnNUg3Fk_Q6YWPWabNdV0yMuyx65b These are cool anyhow.